# Difference between create table syntax in teradata

Tags: database, teradata

I'm unable to figure out the difference between below teradata syntax. Could someone please help.

```
CREATE TABLE EMP_TABLE_BACKUP AS EMP_TABLE WITH DATA;
```

vs

```
CREATE TABLE EMP_TABLE_BACKUP AS (SELECT * FROM EMP_TABLE ) WITH DATA;
```

Comment: I believe there is no difference between the two. Both will create tables with same structure and data. You can use different names in each query and test if there is any difference by using SHOW TABLE command. Typically, there shouldn't be any

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are huge differences between `CREATE TABLE AS existing_table` and `CREATE TABLE AS (SELECT...)`:

When you copy an existing table most of the attributes on table & column level are inherited, e.g. `SET` or `MULTISET`, Primary & Secondary Indexes, `NOT NULL`, `COMPRESS`. Only Triggers & Foreign Keys are not copied.

But when you materialize a `SELECT`, most attributes are lost, e.g. every column will be NULLable & and the PI probably defaults to the 1st column.

You get all details in the [Teradata manuals](http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_15_10/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035_1184_151K/Create_Table-Details.013.114.html)

Comment: Thanks!. Another question - Is fallback enabled on tables by default ?

Comment: @Pugazh: The default for `FALLBACK` is set on a database level, see **dbc.DatabasesV.ProtectionType**, `F` or `N`.